# ¿Cómo traducir al español el término "crackpot"?

Tags: traducción

En inglés, el término [*crackpot*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank_(person)) se usa en el ámbito científico para designar a una persona que defiende ideas erróneas, disparatadas o absurdas, y que no reconoce evidencia en contra. Me pregunto cómo puede uno traducirlo al español; he visto muchas personas así de habla hispana, y están muy esparcidas en la sociedad actual.

Comment: "Zafado" en el sentido de "chiflado", "fuera de lugar", "incoherente". "Zarpado" como "fanático" o "desubicado". "Tirado de las mechas" como imposible, descabellado, improbable, inadmisible, irrisorio, jalado de los pelos.

Comment: Crackpot no se dice solo en el ámbito cientifico.  Esto es un error.

Comment: También, depende quien se hable y en que época, va desde "visionario", "incomprendido" hasta "intolerante", "adelantado", "alocado" etc. Eso sería lo más estándar porque he visto otras traducciones mucho más regionales y graciosas.

Comment: Descuadrado también lo he leído.

Answer (score 3):

Desconozco los matices exactos de la palabra crackpot en inglés pero me temo que las entradas en los diccionarios de Oxford y Cambridge contradicen tu afirmación de que se emplee en ámbitos científicos con esa acepción que apuntas.

Según estos diccionarios, respectivamente tenemos

> [**crackpot**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/crackpot)
> **coloquial** 
> An eccentric or foolish person.

> [**crackpot**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/crackpot)
> **informal**
> a person who is silly or stupid

He marcado en negrita que ambos diccionarios consideran esta palabra de uso coloquial e informal. No tiene un ámbito ciéntifico.

Normalmente fool o silly se traducen al español como **tonto**. Puedes [consultar el DLE](https://dle.rae.es/tonto) y comprobar si alguno de los distintos significados de dicha palabra se ajustan a lo que buscas. Uno de los sinónimos de tonto y de [**estúpido**](https://dle.rae.es/est%C3%BApido?m=form) (palabras que aparecen en las definiciones de arriba), aunque quizás con un grado más alto de insulto aún, es [**imbécil**](https://dle.rae.es/imb%C3%A9cil).

Por otro lado, uno de los sinónimos de crackpot indicado por el diccionario Cambridge es

> [**screwball**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/screwball)
> a person who behaves in a strange and funny way

A esta definición se acercan mucho más estos epítetos hispanos

> [**flipado**](https://dle.rae.es/flipado)
>
> 1. m. y f. **coloq**. Esp. Persona que está bajo los efectos de una droga, **o lo parece.**

> **[grillado](https://dle.rae.es/grillado)**
> 2. adj. **coloq**. Loco, chiflado.

Nótese que ambas son de ámbito **coloquial**, al igual que crackpot.

Por último, la traducción literal de crackpot, **olla** rota, me lleva a dos expresiones en español bastante comunes que juegan con que olla y **cabeza** son sinónimos en determinados contextos

> [**írsele a alguien la olla**](https://dle.rae.es/olla?m=form)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Esp. írsele la cabeza (‖ perturbársele la razón).

> **tener una pedrada en la **cabeza****

No he encontrado referencias en el DLE para esta segunda pero creo que casi se explica por si misma, al recibir una pedrada, un fuerte golpe con una piedra que ha sido lanzada contra su cabeza, el sujeto ve mermadas momentánea o perennemente sus capacidades mentales, entre las que se encuentra el [**raciocinio**](https://dle.rae.es/raciocinio).

No quiero terminar sin apuntar que no creo que los hispanohablantes tengamos nada que envidiar a los angloparlantes en cuanto a cantidad de crackpots. En todas partes cuecen habas ;-P

Comment: As a wild guess a crackpot is someone whose ideas do not hold water like a cracked pot. I agree with you that it is not used particularly in the science field. Crackpot ideas might include believing the earth is flat, that a perpetual motion machine is possible, ...

Answer (score 3):

Para designar a una persona que defiende ideas erróneas, disparatadas o absurdas, y que no reconoce evidencia en contra se podrían considerar:

[**Ofuscado**](https://dle.rae.es/ofuscar?):

> 3. tr. Trastornar, conturbar o confundir las ideas, alucinar. U. t. c. prnl.

[**Obcecado**](https://dle.rae.es/obcecar?):

> 1. tr. Cegar, deslumbrar u ofuscar. *Los nervios obcecaron a Juan y no supo contestar a las preguntas*. U. t. c. prnl. *Se obceca en su idea y no reacciona.*

y especialmente [**contumaz**](https://dle.rae.es/contumaz?):

> 1. adj. Rebelde, porfiado y tenaz en mantener un error.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que **charlatán** o **charlatana** podría servir como una traducción adecuada.

Tal vez el término esté más asociado con una especie de médico falso (también denominado un "quack" en inglés), por ejemplo un vendedor de "medicina" que no sirve. Sin importar si lo sabe o si cree que funcione o no, pero creo que "crackpot" insinua que sí cree en su propio pedo ;) Por eso está percibido como loco por la mayoría a diferencia de un estafador común.